# Is there a word for someone who is a regular computer user but not an expert?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for a person who uses the computer regularly and is adept at doing what she has to do or wants to do on the computer, but has no interest whatsoever in its hardware or software innards, nor in allowing it to take over her life?  The word is not "agnostic" nor "Luddite".  I have a particular person in mind, who calls herself a "computer dren".  Is there an actual word?

Comment: *Dren*, as in *Nerd* spelled backwards?  Anyway, the opposite of an enthusiast *is* a detractor. Someone who's in the middle just *is*.

Comment: [Dren](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=dren) could be used in a derogatory sense.

Comment: All this is helpful, but doesn't capture the attitude of this person -- the instant something goes wrong, she needs help.  It is always a simple problem.  No one minds, because she is helpful in what she does best -- analysis and writing.  Example, someone else formats her work.  The words, sentences, paragraphs and pages are lovely, concise English but the format is

Comment: I think "computer literate" is the best of the answers, but it doesn't capture the indifference approaching distain this person feels about any detail of the workings of the computer that does not immediately help her in her task -- analysis and writing.  It may be a generational thing.

Comment: Reminds me of this Tech Support Cheat Sheet http://xkcd.com/627/

Comment: An interesting opinion piece (and comments) "I don't know anything about computers." http://blog.carolynworks.com/?p=388

Comment: Sounds like the word you're looking for is simply "User"

Comment: I would *not* call the user you are describing "adept" then.

Comment: an ***Avid*** user

Comment: If words, sentences, and paragraphs are her thing but she can't format them on the computer, what does she do on that computer that makes her "adept" at using it?  It sounds like she types words, sentences, and paragraphs into a word processing program then has someone else actually use the program to format her work.  "Ready for retirement" may be the phrase you're looking for.

Comment: @EllieK  Hellion, in a comment towards the end understands perfectly what I meant: "..... the desired meaning: someone who has no interest in pursuing the subject beyond what is required of them (though they are professional enough to be good at the stuff that is actually required)."  This person is brilliant at analysis, synthesis and clear, cogent writing.  She does not, however, worship at the altar of the computer.  .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could call her a **casual** computer user.

> **Casual**
>
> (1) :  feeling or showing little concern :  nonchalant (*a casual approach to cooking*)
>
> (2) :  lacking a high degree of interest or devotion (*casual sports fans*, *casual readers*)
>
> (3) :  done without serious intent or commitment (*casual sex*)
>
> (Merriam-Webster)

Someone who's casual about something does it but is not really passionate about it. In contrast, a computer nerd or geek uses computers and is passionate about them as well.

Comment: Use of "casual user" in this way tends to mean they don't use a computer very often, rather than they are a heavy or moderate computer user, but they are very casual in their attitudes towards it as a tool.

Comment: If you specified that the person is a "frequent but casual computer user," then it would be clear that you're using "casual" in the "not devoted" sense of the word.

Comment: I don't know if I'd describe someone in a typical office job, who could spend 20-30hrs+ per week on a computer a casual user though, even though most wouldn't know the workings of it

Answer (score 33):

> **computer-literate**
>
> *adjective*
>
> (Of a person) having sufficient knowledge and skill to be able to use
>   computers; familiar with the operation of computers.
>   <sub>[ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/computer-literate)</sub>

There's also

> **computer-savvy**

The March 2008 edition of the Oxford English Dictionary added
[computer-savvy](http://public.oed.com/the-oed-today/recent-updates-to-the-oed/previous-updates/march-2008-update/) as a subordinate entry under **computer** so it is recognized; @ermanen graciously provided the definition which I didn't have access to:

> **Computer-savvy**
>
> having a thorough practical knowledge of computers
>   <sub>[OED]</sub>

The adjective definition

> **savvy**
>
> *adjective*
>
> :  having or showing perception, comprehension, or shrewdness
>   especially in practical matters
>
> Examples of SAVVY
>
> She's a very **savvy** investor. He is **savvy** about computers.
>   <sub>[Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/savvy)</sub>

Comment: +1 to me computer-literate is the idiomatic expression that fits best & doesn't connote too high a level of computer ability

Comment: It may depend on the perspective of your audience too. For example, to someone who works in IT, a person being defined as "computer savvy" would be exactly what the OP is looking for. For someone of little computer knowledge, "computer savvy" may imply a greater ability level than desired.

Comment: Then I am a regular computer user but I must be computer illiterate :)

Comment: ÷1 for computer-literate but I balk at -savvy,

Comment: @Rache, I'd take computer-savvy off the answer if I knew that all the upvotes refer to computer-literate - which I suspect but don't know for a fact.  That's the drawback with listing more than one word in an answer.  The March 2008 edition of the Oxford English Dictionary did add "computer-savvy" as a subordinate entry under "computer" so it is recognized (I don't have access to the definition), though your objection might be that it isn't applicable. http://public.oed.com/the-oed-today/recent-updates-to-the-oed/previous-updates/march-2008-update/

Comment: *Computer-savvy*: having a thorough practical knowledge of computers *[OED]*

Answer (score 13):

I'd use "power user" -- it implies that a user is skilled but not enough that they would be considered a "super user" or system administrator

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_user

Comment: To me, a power user is well above the average level of computer literacy. A power user is an expert and the question explicitly asks for a word for non-experts.

Comment: The "average level of computer literary" does not correlate with "a person who uses the computer regularly and is adept at doing what she has to do or wants to do on the computer"

A power user is a user who is adept at using a computer but not to the point where they do so professionally (or in-depth in general) -- just someone who knows their way around on a competent++ level.

Comment: @jimjamflimflam I'd argue that a power user is more than just competent, but rather a lower level or targeted expert.  I am quite savvy at using Microsoft Office, but when trying to do stuff in excel I occasionally have to look things up, and more complicated tasks require me to either do some googling or ask someone else.  An Excel power user knows all the ins and outs of Excel - they're the person you might ask how to do something.  They have custom macros and hotkeys, etc.  A computer power user has customized their computer extensively to make things more efficient and look "better".

Comment: An extension to this is:  A power user would likely be capable and competent in using the command line to do tasks and able to debug many of their own issues (how-to's, crashes, blue screens, etc) and come up with a solution without calling support.  The OP doesn't seem to be describing such a person.

Comment: I am an administrator in IT, and what the OP is describing I would call a "power user."

Answer (score 9):

I've always thought the word ***user*** itself, without further qualification, expresses the concept "*uses the computer regularly and is adept at doing what she has to do or wants to do on the computer, but has no interest whatsoever in its hardware or software innards, nor in allowing it to take over her life*".

In the same way the user of a mowing machine is perhaps adept in doing what they have to do, with no interest in its innards.

One could perhaps say ***end user***, to rub it in.

Comment: As anyone who works in IT knows, *users* are usually, and by default,  the opposite of "adept" at actually using the things! ;)

Comment: @MarvMills What everyone working in IT knows might not even be true, you know. It's a defence mechanism ;)

Comment: no, it's actually true.

Comment: To be fair, IT rarely hears from the people that know what they are doing.  So they're perception is likely skewed quite a bit.

Comment: The “user” is the simply the person that will use something, not necessarily someone who will use it *regularly*. In the user-centred design literature, it's not unusual to read about catering to various types of users from novice to expert. In that context at least, the word “user” has no additional connotation. Also, users are often experts in their domain but not necessarily at using the machine itself.

Comment: "To rub it in" -- rub what in? The question is asking for vocabulary, not value judgements.

Comment: User is the correct word. An expert in the innards of a computer is a computer hardware engineer; an expert in programming is a developer or applications programmer. Computer user is... a user, not an expert. I laughed a little at "end user".  That would probably be a good description for anyone who regularly used a computer at work but doesn't program or work in IT, development etc.

Comment: My wife describes herself as a "user without the silent L."

Comment: As someone who works in IT, "end user" is what we use most frequently. It doesn't imply they know anything above basic level stuff like "power user" does, but it's more descriptive than "user".

Answer (score 4):

Aggregating a couple of the answers, I think there is a spectrum here and the right phrase depends a bit on the exact skill level and perhaps even the context you use it in:

- **Computer literate** implies someone who is competent in basic usage scenarios (doesn't require handholding usually), but is not necessarily an expert user. This person probably understands little if anything that it happening under the covers. Contrast it with the widely used *computer illiterate*
- **Computer savvy** implies someone who is competent in both basic usage and a wide-range of advanced usage scenarios. Again, this person's proficiency is not about understanding what the computer is doing but rather in understanding how to make it do what they want.
- **Power user** to me implies one or two paths of expertise. This could be someone who is not just good, but is expert at molding software to their will. This could also be someone who understands enough about what's happening underneath (kernel level, services level, or even hardware level) that they are not the logical conclusion of the user but rather someone who has enough knowledge to generalize to new situations well.

I think this is a highly subjective area though, and this is just what these terms mean to me with both a technical support and software development background.

Answer (score 3):

There's the hacker slang, [*luser*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luser), though it's rather derogatory, even if they believe you if you claim "oh, it's just short for 'local user'".

Answer (score 1):

I describe the person as having a **functional** understanding of computers. The person knows enough to operate certain processes but not enough to troubleshoot them.

> **func·tion·al**
>
> adjective
>
> 1. of or having a special activity, purpose, or task; relating to the way in which something works or operates.
>    "there are important functional differences between left and right brain"

Answer (score 0):

Since nerdism or geekery would be the exception rather than the rule, in terms of users' attitudes to computers, any term that describes someone adept at using the tool should suffice.

Use of the term [accomplished](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/accomplished?s=t) will convey the meaning they are adept in their use, without implying the user is also a nerd or geek.

> **adjective**
>
> 2. highly skilled; expert: 
>      an accomplished pianist.
>
> *www.dictionary.com*

EDIT: Since posting this answer the OP has been modified so that the title of the question specifically precludes "Expert", which invalidates this answer.

Answer (score 0):

The Hacker's Dictionary has a couple of terms that might be of interest.  The more obvious is [*real user*](http://www.hacker-dictionary.com/terms/real-user), but [*chemist*](http://www.hacker-dictionary.com/terms/chemist) has been used.  For comparison the suggestions *luser* and simply *user* are worth looking up there.

I'd suggest that you're best off with *-- user*, perhaps *ordinary user*.

Answer (score 0):

**Dilettante**

As per Google definition: Dilettante means a person who cultivates an area of interest, such as the arts, without real commitment or knowledge.

Not sure anything particularly for Computers. 
**Amateur** is also closer .

Though as mentioned in previous answers **Computer-Savvy** or **Net Savvy** are good options too.

**Dern** is an actual word and has various meaning in various context but definitely not what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

"Client" is what developers use for the person who has nothing to do with the technical details. Other words devs use are "user", "standard user" and "front-end user".

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you also have a look at **digerati**, defined by [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/digerati)

> persons well versed in computer use and technology.

Here the word *versed* takes care of their awareness of technology and the overall sentence doesn't suggest anything related to interest in hardware.

Comment: You really are going back in the archives!  Thanks for the interest, but Digerati doesn't work because:  " person ....has no interest whatsoever in its hardware or software..." This was one of my first questions and I would have made it clearer if I were writing it today, but I was trying to get across an absolute refusal to learn one tiny thing more than she needed to know to do what she had to do.  The computer to her was more convenient than a long yellow legal pad but no more intrinsically interesting.  Glad to see you back.

Answer (score -1):

What about "enthusiast"?

from Chambers Concise Dictionary:

> **enthusiast** *noun* someone filled with enthusiasm, especially for a particular subject; a fan or devotee.

Comment: That seems to be quite the opposite of the desired meaning: someone who has no interest in pursuing the subject beyond what is required of them (though they are professional enough to be good at the stuff that is actually required).